# How can I convert date in unix epoch format to ruby datetime for a datetime column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The date is coming from an imported xml that gives a 13 digit string (unix epoch time format).

The following snippet causes the resulting column value to be set to 1970-01-01

```
  seconds=msg.time_stamp_long.to_i/1000
  time=Time.at(seconds).utc.to_s
  msg.time_stamp=time
  msg.save
```

How to get the correct format for a DateTime column?

Comment: Do You want to save in db `1970-01-01` ? can you up more ex: msg fields, ... you use format `strftime`. ex: `msg.created_at.strftime('%F')`

Comment: My problem is that 1970-01-01 isn't right It should be a real date derived from a 13 digit string from xml import It seems the data was originally in unix time format and needed to be converted to ruby datetime format first and being a string was problematic also

Comment: Thanks, it's a 13 digit string meaning it's a string but it's all numbers

Comment: What DBMS? Can you give and actual example? What is the DB schema for that column? Are you sure it's what you expected? "...a real date..."  give an example of what you expect to see. Don't describe it, give us exactly what you are seeing and what you want to see.

Comment: Sorry but this is a collosal XY question - you're asking about a solution which isn't even needed in the first place instead of just asking how to parse a unix epoch. `DateTime` is a Ruby class. Not an actual database column format. When you use `add_column :foo, :bar, :date_time` the database adapter will create the column with the appropriate format for your RBDMS.

Comment: You don't have actually care about the format - just pass input to your model that it understands like an instance of Date, DateTime, TimeWithZone or even ISO string. Then when you persist the model the database adapter will handle any conversion for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Time.at(1663681609392 / 1000).to_datetime
```

or if it's a string

```
Time.at("1663681609392".to_i / 1000).to_datetime
```

Be aware that unix time is epoch UTC time. Time and DateTime can get tricky in Ruby and in Rails. Make sure you are getting the time you expect. You may need to look into methods like `.in_time_zone`

To use your variables from the question:

```
msg.update(time_stamp: Time.at(msg.time_stamp_long / 1000))
```

is all you really need. As Max pointed out the DB adapter will handle the rest. But when you go to display or manipulate dates/times in Rails you might want to look into Date, Time, TimeWithZone, DateTime, etc. to understand the options that are out there and how they apply to your use case.

Comment: Also I see you are converting to a string before saving as the date-time column. Not sure why you would do that. That is why I asked for the schema.

Comment: I can't remember why I used to_s This became so difficult I'm now trying to solve it in mysql without using ruby or ror Mysql has a from_unixtime function that returns null when applied to the 13 digit numbers I have in time_stamp_long The schemas not really relevant I don't think because the data source is xml

Comment: to_datetime is a function that converts strings to datetimes, not integers to datetimes

Comment: Here's an example of one of the values of time_stamp_long 1663681609392 What date would you translate that into, how would you do it, how would you store that in a mysql datetime column? That's all I wanna know

Comment: Did you even read or try my answer? `to_datetime` is a method on both`String` and `Time` classes.

Comment: Here's the value I need to store as datetime (i think) 1663681609392

Comment: Also, you are missing something in your data format. Your time_stamp_long translates to `Fri Dec 20 20:23:12 PST 54689`. So unless you are looking for the year 54689, something is missing. My answer works. It's your data (or what you know about it) that is incorrect.

Comment: Oh, it's in milliseconds. So I need to divide by 1000 in my answer.

Comment: The answer should work. As Max pointed out to your question, the DB adapter will handle putting it into the DB. You just hand it something that Rails understands as a date_time, date, or time object.

Comment: Beartech: You're right, just needed to add to_i to enable division